# Fabric.js dynamically add/remove elements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I started working with the Fabric.js library after looking into several libraries to see which fits better for what I need to do, and finally choose Fabric.js (also tried with Paper.js or Chars.js or Raphael.js).

I'm still fighting with the problem of trying to dynamically add/remove segments to a Path (I chose Path elements because I found that it is the best option to make it work but also works fine with Polyline element), but it seems impossible to do it.

This is a part of the code:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

//Seteo un array para todos los canvas que va a tener el grafico
var canvas= Array();

//Seteo un array para lineas guias que va a tener el grafico
var guias= Array();

//Seteo un array con todos los colores posibles
var color=Array();

//Seteo un array para todas las variables / lineas que va a tener el grafico
var graficos= Array();

var polyline= Array();

//Seteo un array para todas las variables / puntos que va a tener el grafico
var points= Array();

//Capturo todos los elementos canvas de la clase especifica
var Ocanvas;

//Capturo el evento de Drag&Drop
var isDragging=false;
var dragPoints={x:0,y:0};

//Se generan random un cantidad X de colores (cantidad= variable total)
for(var c=0;c <= 500; c++){
    var rojo=getRandomInt(0,155);
    var azul=getRandomInt(0,155);
    var verde=getRandomInt(0,155);
    transparencia=getRandomInt(5,10)/10;
    color[c]="rgba("+rojo+","+verde+","+azul+","+transparencia+")";
}

//Seteo el total de elementos que deseo mostrar en cada canvas (siempre tomar en cuenta que comienza desde 0 a contar)
var total=3;

//Seteo el nro de elemento inicial de cada Path
var iPath=0;

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //Capturo todos los elementos canvas de la clase especifica
    Ocanvas=jQuery("canvas.canvas-basic");

    //Obtengo el ancho de las columnas de canvas
    var OriginalWidth=parseInt(Ocanvas.innerWidth());

    //Obtengo el alto de las columnas de canvas
    var OriginalHeight=parseInt(Ocanvas.innerHeight());

    var actual_zoom=0;

    //Defino el valor del ancho de las lineas de los graficos
    var Vstroke=2.5;

    //var canvas_color = color[getRandomInt(0,500)];
    var canvas_color="#E6E6E6";

    jQuery.each(Ocanvas, function(i, v){

        var aux_id = jQuery(this).attr("id");

        canvas[i] = new fabric.Canvas(aux_id, {
            containerClass:"canvas-conteiner",
            backgroundColor: canvas_color,
            renderOnAddRemove:false,
            width: OriginalWidth,
            height: OriginalHeight,
            selection:false,
            stateful: false,
        });

        //Creo una linea con 2 pixeles mas de largo para que 
        guias[i] = new fabric.Line([0,-1, OriginalWidth+2, -1],{
            top:OriginalHeight,
            left:-1, //muevo la linea a la posicion -1 para evitar que queden espacios entre los canvas
            strokeWidth:0.5,
            stroke: "#f00",
            lockMovementY: true,
            lockRotation: true,
            selectable: false,
            //stroke: color[getRandomInt(0,500)],
        });

        canvas[i].add(guias[i]);

        canvas[i].labelGuia=new labelGuia({
            backgroundColor: color[getRandomInt(0,500)],
        });

        canvas[i].add(canvas[i].labelGuia);
    });

    canvas.renderAll();

    //Agrego funcionamiento al evento de movimiento del mouse
    jQuery("body").delegate(".upper-canvas.canvas-basic", "mousemove", event, function(obj){

        if(isDragging){
            jQuery(this).addClass("cursor-move");
        }

        var strokeColor=color[getRandomInt(0,500)];

        //alert(strokeColor);

        //var index= jQuery(this).parents(".col-canvas").attr("data-index");

        if(canvas.getZoom()>1){
            obj.offsetY= (obj.offsetY / canvas.getZoom());
        }

        lastmove=0;

        lastpositionY=obj.offsetY+lastmove;
        var valY=lastpositionY;

        guias.set({
            opacity:1,
            top:valY,
            stroke:"#000",
        }); 

        guias.bringToFront();
        
        canvas.renderAll();
    });

    jQuery("body").delegate(".upper-canvas.canvas-basic", "mousedown", event, function(e){
        isDragging=true;
        dragPoints.x = e.offsetX;
        dragPoints.y = e.offsetY;
        jQuery(this).css("cursor","move");
    });

    jQuery("body").delegate(".upper-canvas.canvas-basic", "mouseup", event, function(e){
        if( dragPoints.x != e.offsetX && dragPoints.y != e.offsetY){
            //console.log("isDragging x0:"+ dragPoints.x+" y0:"+ dragPoints.y + " / x1:"+e.offsetX+" y1:"+e.offsetY);
            var posX=graficos.get("top");
            var moveX=posX + (e.offsetY-dragPoints.y);
            graficos.set({
                top: moveX,
            });

            canvas.renderAll();
        }
        jQuery(this).removeClass("cursor-move");
        isDragging=false;
    });

    //Agrego funcionamiento al evento de la "rueda" del mouse
    jQuery(".upper-canvas.canvas-basic").on("mousewheel", function (e) {
        var strokeWidthWheel=1;
        
        var delta = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 1200);
        var pointer=e;

        var actual_points={
            x:e.offsetX, 
            y:e.offsetY,
        };

        var movePoints={ 
            x:e.offsetX,
            y:e.offsetY+50
        }

        lastpositionY=pointer.offsetY / canvas.getZoom();

        var valY=lastpositionY;

        delta=Math.round(delta * 100) /100; //Esto esta hecho asi para que el valor quede con 2 decimales nada mas.

        actual_zoom= Math.round( canvas.getZoom() * 100) /100;
        
        if(delta < 0 && (actual_zoom + delta) > 1){
            //canvas.zoomToPoint(actual_points, actual_zoom+delta);
            //canvas.setZoom(actual_zoom+delta);
            canvas.zoomToPoint(movePoints, actual_zoom+delta);
            graficos.setScaleY(actual_zoom+delta);
            //graficos.setOriginX(actual_points.x);
            strokeWidthWheel= guias.get("strokeWidth")+delta;
        }else if(delta > 0){
            //canvas.setZoom(actual_zoom+delta);
            canvas.zoomToPoint(movePoints, actual_zoom+delta);
            graficos.setScaleY(actual_zoom+delta);
            //graficos.setOriginX(actual_points.x);
            strokeWidthWheel= guias.get("strokeWidth")-delta;
        }           

        if(strokeWidthWheel<0.5){
            strokeWidthWheel=0.5;
        }

        guias.set({
            opacity:1,
            top:valY,
            strokeWidth: strokeWidthWheel,
        });

        //console.log(canvas[0]);

        if((actual_zoom + delta) == 1){
            canvas.zoomToPoint({x:0,y:0}, 1);
            graficos.set({top:-1});
            guias.set({
                left:-1
            });
            canvas.setCoords();
            canvas.fxCenterObjectV();
        }

        canvas.renderAll();
    });

    var xCount=0;

    //Genero graficos de forma aleatoria 
    jQuery.each(canvas, function(i, v){
        for(var j=0; j< total; j++){
            var pos_j=j%total;
            var posX=getRandomInt(50,65)*(pos_j+1);
            var posY=0;             

            graficos[xCount] = new fabric.Path("M "+posX+",-1 L "+posX+","+posY
                , {
                    strokeWidth: Vstroke,
                    stroke: color[getRandomInt(0,500)],
                    originX: 'left',
                    //originY: 'top',
                    left:posX,
                    top:0,
                    opacity:1,
                    hasBorders:false,
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    fill: "transparent",
                    lockScalingX:true,
                }
            );

            graficos[xCount].posicionY=posY;

            graficos[xCount].posicionX=posX;

            points[xCount]=Array();

            canvas[i].add(graficos[xCount]);

            //Beta Test use Polyline instead of Path
            polyline[xCount] = new fabric.Polyline( [ {x: posX, y: posY } ]
                , {
                    strokeWidth: Vstroke,
                    stroke: color[getRandomInt(0,500)],
                    originX: 'left',
                    //originY: 'top',
                    left:posX,
                    top:0,
                    opacity:1,
                    hasBorders:false,
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    fill: "transparent",
                    lockScalingX:true,
                }
            );

            canvas[i].add(polyline[xCount]);

            xCount++;
        }
    });

});
var itemToRemove=0;

var oldPath=Array();

function cachePath(init, max, ar){
    if(ar instanceof Array){
        var len=ar.length;
        if(len>0){
            if(init < max){

            }else{
                return false;   
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

var CONST_escale=25;

window.setInterval(function(){
    
    for(var j=0; j < graficos.length; j++){
        graficos[j].posicionY=graficos[j].get("minY")+iPath*CONST_escale;
        //graficos[j].path[iPath]=Array("L", graficos[j].posicionX, graficos[j].posicionY);
        polyline[j].points[iPath]={x:graficos[j].posicionX, y:graficos[j].posicionY};
        //graficos[j].posicionY = graficos[j].posicionY + 1;
        //points[j][iPath]={ x: graficos[j].posicionX, y: graficos[j].get("minY")+iPath};

        //console.log("posY:"+parseInt(graficos[j].posicionY) +" - Height: "+ parseInt(canvas.getHeight()));

        if( parseInt(graficos[j].posicionY) > parseInt(canvas.getHeight()) ){
            //graficos[j].setTop(graficos[j].get("top") - 1);
            graficos[j].setTop(graficos[j].get("top") - CONST_escale);
            if(iPath>=10){
                //graficos[j].set({stroke:color[getRandomInt(0,500) ] } );
                //polyline[j].points.splice(iPath-10,1);
                polyline[j].points[iPath-10]=null;
                //polyline[j].points[iPath].set({stroke:color[getRandomInt(0,500) ] } );
                //points[j].splice(itemToRemove,1);
                //itemToRemove++;
                //console.log("points["+j+"]:"+points[j].length);
                //graficos[j].path.shift();
                //graficos[j].path[0][0]="M";
                //console.log(graficos[j].path[0][0]);
            }
        }

        if(iPath==100*itemToRemove){
            //var oldPath[j][itemToRemove]=graficos[j].path.splice(100, graficos[j].path.length-100);
            //graficos[j].path=graficos[j].path.splice(itemToRemove,100);
            //itemToRemove++;
            //console.log("points["+j+"]:"+points[j].length);
            //graficos[j].path.shift();
            //graficos[j].path[0][0]="M";
            //console.log(graficos[j].path[0][0]);
            itemToRemove++;
        }

        if(canvas[j] != undefined ){
            //console.log(canvas[j].labelGuia);
            canvas[j].labelGuia.updateText("label: "+ iPath * CONST_escale * j);
        }
    }
    
    if( (iPath % 1) == 0 ){
        for(var j=0; j < graficos.length; j++){
            var rand=getRandomInt(-65,65);
            var pos_j=j%total;
            var pos_X=65*(pos_j+1) + rand;
            graficos[j].posicionX = pos_X;
            var pos_Y=graficos[j].get("minY")+iPath;

            graficos[j].path[iPath]=Array("L", pos_X, pos_Y*CONST_escale);

            points[j][iPath]=Array();
            points[j][iPath][0]=graficos[j].posicionX;
            points[j][iPath][1]=graficos[j].get("minY")+iPath;
        }
    } 

    iPath++;

    canvas.renderAll();
},500);
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/17ueLva2/17/](http://jsfiddle.net/17ueLva2/17/)

I have 4 Canvas elements (in the future it will be possible to make this more dynamic, user could add/remove Canvas) where I need to draw between 1 and 4 lines with segments (all segments will have the same height, in other words x value its the same for all). In the example to make it easiest I draw 3 lines in each one.

I also have the need that the paths I dynamically draw will grow and grow (some cases could be drawing for 4 or 6 hours constantly and every 1/2 second will be added 1 element to each Path) so I will like to remove some old paths after they disappear from visualisation (let's say I have a canvas with 300px of height and if that segment's height is 500px then I want to remove the first px of each path and make the path height always reamins in 500px).

I tried using the Javascript functions `shift` and `splice`. In each case, after removing the elements in path array of the Fabrics Path the code broke or the graphics even disappeared.

I will need to know if what I'm trying to do is possible or if someone with more experience could give me some help with this.

Also, the amount of time that the system is drawing without stopping could be between 2hs and 10hs so its really important to remove "old" paths.

Also once I can add/remove paths-segments without breaking the graphics, I will try to make dynamically update when the user drag and drop the graphics.

This is for a real-time system that I'm developing.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a look at your fiddle. I am not entirely sure what you are wanting as I can not read spanish but I have to say that you are going about keeping data the wrong way. The canvas is not a place to store data, it is a window with which to view data. You store the data in an appropriate array or data store and render a view of that data on demand.

Javascript is more than capable of displaying a screen full of data in realtime. As it is only possible to see one screen full of information at a time having 6 live view seems redundant.

Store the data you are recording into an array. Create a render function that renders that data onto the canvas, only when the canvas is in view and only the part of the data that will fit onto the canvas (if you want to see the last hour, only render the last hour, not the entire sample set as you are doing now), and only at a resolution that can rendered (no point rendering 20000 samples on a view 200 pixels wide. Rather get the mean of every 100 samples and only render 200 means, or also get the min, max if there is need for accurate visualization.)

It's too much work to show you code for this, but the closest thing I can think of that you should think about and investigate is a waveform viewer used to view audio and music. They are designed to show samples from very large data sets (10s of millions of samples) and can do this in real time. They do this by rendering a view (part) of the data, not by rendering all the data and then zooming and panning to what you want to see.

I hope I have understood what you are trying to do. If not ignore my answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, its a good approach to solve what I'm doing.

The interval where it renders new paths I made it to replace the "real time" data. 
About have only one graphic or canvas It's impossible that is a requeriment and in a future I will try it to do dynamic (add or remove Canvas according the needs of the user). Also the graphics (Paths) to show are relative because could be from 1 to 4 on each Canvas.
Again, thanks for your answer i will take a look on implement that (and sorry for the spanish comments in the code).
Regards,